# PHP SOAP client and namespaces

Tags: php, soap, namespaces

I can POST the following xml file to a webservice and I get a response ID is I am expecting.

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <Body>
    <logon xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <username>USRNAME</username>
        <password>b5059e852207a</password>
      </logon>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I'm now trying to convert this to use a PHP SOAP client. I make the following call

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient('http://*********.co.uk/ws-b/WebservicesPTP.asmx?wsdl');
```

and I can get a list of functions:

```
$functions = $soapclient->__getFunctions();
```

but when I try and use the logon method:

```
$params = array('username' => 'USRNAME', 'password' => 'b5059e852207a');
$response = $soapclient->logon($params);
```

I don't get any return at all.

I suspect it's something to to with the namespaces but I've got two one on the envelope and one on the logon. Do I need these and if so how do I add these to the SOAP Client?

**EDIT:**
I'm getting the following PHP error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] rt.exception.RTException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Comment: It's hard to say what is wrong because we don't know anything about WSDL. You can track your request body using: [`__getLastRequest()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php). Remeber about set `trace=>true` in SoapClient constructor.

Comment: I've just tried that but I'm not even getting past the logon call. If I put a simple testing message after the call I don't get that output.

Comment: I'm getting the following PHP error:-                                                                                              PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] rt.exception.RTException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Piotr Olaszewski. Finally got this working. The problem wasn't namesapces but simply a missing 'session' parameter on the logon method. Disappointingly this caused the call just to fail so I couldn't use the _getLastRequest method.